# Is there a replacement for Bixby JavaScript API module textLib?

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

The Bixby Import and search template uses a library module textLib which throws an error due to the library having been deprecated. The template uses a javascript file named "transaction_util.js" that requires the library via `var textLib = require('textLib')`. The library contains functions that were used for various text-related functions for fuzzy matching.

Is there a replacement module or a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the inconvenience. We had an emergency update to the template capsule. You can try it now and should use `externalTextLib` which is included in the template.

If you already started your coding, you may want to create a new template capsules, copy and paste code/lib/externalTextLib.js to your existing capsule and change the line to `var textLib = require('externalTextLib')`, which should work without any additional coding change.

Or start a new project with the new template. It might be a safer option.